# Problem replicating voltage regulator circuit in LTSpice

Tags: voltage-regulator, comparator

I'm new to voltage regulation circuits and have a circuit from https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoaa20/snoaa20.pdf that I've used as inspiration:

[image]

My circuit in LTSpice is below:

[image]

The Zener diode is 7.5V.

The regulation is working as far as the comparators are concerned (they activate if \$V1>17V\$ or \$V1<12 V\$).

However, my understanding of using voltage regulators in this way is that you would use them to increase the voltage at the gate of the MOSFET (P-channel) so that \$V_g\$ is close to \$V_s\$ and thus turn the MOSFET to OFF (thus protecting the load).

However, now that I'm simulating a similar circuit, it seems that either I've drafted my circuit incorrectly or my theory is wrong. I say this because when the comparators activate the voltage they send only partially reaches \$V_g\$.

My results at \$V1=19V\$ are: \$V_g=14.3V\$, \$V_s=19V\$

This doesn't seem useful for setting the MOSFET to OFF. I would have expected \$V_g=V1-Z_{7.5}+V1=19V-7.5V+19V=30.5V\$

Comment: How can you possibly get 30.5V in a dc circuit with a maximum supply voltage of 19V?

Comment: Why did you tie the two LT1413 outputs together? Using the default `PMOS` will **not** give you a magic power MOSFET -- you need to select one from the database or add your custom `VDMOS` `.MODEL`. Not lastly, LT1413 is an opamp, not a comparator.

Comment: Tying two opamp outputs together will cause a lot of current to flow between them. Try getting the base circuit first. What did you want to do with the 2nd opamp?

Comment: Also your transistor is backwards from what it is in TI's circuit. With it that way the body diode, which while not explicitly shown is generally there, will be forward biased and you'll just get your supply voltage minus the diode drop at the load.

Comment: @Miron the first activates if the supply voltage is over 17V and the second activates if it's below 15V. Any tips on how I should connect the comparators if the outputs shouldn't be connected?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen can I not use an opamp as a comparator?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen can you elaborate on "power MOSFETs"? How do I identify a power MOSFET in LTSpice?

Comment: @GodJihyo What difference does it make with the body diode? Is that necessary for using the MOSFET in the way in which I'm trying to use it?

Comment: @p.chives The body diode is a parasitic diode in the MOSFET between the source and drain. The polarity of this diode, and hence which way around you connect the source and drain, will matter. With PMOS this diode is anode to drain, cathode to source. Look up some diagrams of MOSFETs showing the diode and you should be able to see how this would be a problem in your circuit.

Comment: @p.chives You can, but the opamp is meant to be bandlimited and operate within the linear region, so you won't get as sharp responses as a comparator. About connecting the two outputs together, think of it: what happens if one needs to switch on, while the other is still off? If you had open collectors (e.g. LM339), you could do it. And the power MOSFET is the VDMOS. Just `RClick` on it and select one from the list. But first you need to correct its orientation (compare the two pictures).